# Python Flask - Inserting into Tables with a Foreign Key

Tags: python, database, flask, foreign-keys

Needing help with database relations.
I have two tables: funding source and allocation summary, and **4** of the attributes are the same between the two. I'm using a foreign key since there's a one to many relationship between the two tables - a funding source can have many allocations, but an allocation can only have one funding source:

These are my two tables:

```
class FundingSource(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    complete = db.Column(db.String(10), default=False, nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    agency = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    funding_source = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bill = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    tracker = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    allocations = db.relationship('AllocationSummary', backref='allocation', lazy=True) 


class AllocationSummary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # complete 
    # agency 
    # funding_source 
    # bill
    state = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    recipient = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=False)
    funding_source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('funding_source.id'), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, state, eligible_applicant, recipient, amount):
        self.state = state
        self.eligible_applicant = eligible_applicant
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.amount = amount
```

In my allocation summary webpage, I have a button to insert a new allocation, requiring you to fill out the table fields.

Here is my code to insert the new allocation with the required form fields:

```
@main.route("/insert", methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        complete = request.form['complete']
        agency = request.form['agency']
        funding_source = request.form['funding_source']
        bill = request.form['bill']
        state = request.form['state']
        eligible_applicant = request.form['eligible_applicant']
        recipient = request.form['recipient']
        amount = request.form['amount']

        my_alloc = AllocationSummary(state, eligible_applicant, recipient, amount)
        db.session.add(my_alloc)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('alloc_summ'))
```

My question is, how do I include the attributes "complete", "agency", "funding_source", and "bill" to AllocationSummary() and add/commit it to the database if I need those attributes from the FundingSource table?

I guess i'm not understanding what "funding_source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('funding_source.id'), nullable=False)" is suppose to be doing to get the common attributes?

Essentially, I need:

my_alloc = AllocationSummary(**complete**, **agency**, **funding_source**, **bill**, state, eligible_applicant, recipient, amount)

But I can't access those attributes since they're in the FundingSource table, so how can I push them to the database when inserting?

Sorry if all of this is confusing, I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the `allocations` relationship, and it's backref, you  can accomplish it by populating a `AllocationSummary` object and passing that to `FundingSource`. However, this will only work when you remove the `__init__` functions from your models.

```py
    ...
    complete = request.form['complete']
    agency = request.form['agency']
    funding_source = request.form['funding_source']
    bill = request.form['bill']
    state = request.form['state']
    eligible_applicant = request.form['eligible_applicant']
    recipient = request.form['recipient']
    amount = request.form['amount']
    my_fund_src = FundingSource(
        complete=complete,
        agency,
        funding_source,
        bill=bill,
        allocations=[
            AllocationSummary(
                state=state,
                eligible_applicant=eligible_applicant,
                recipient=recipient,
                amount=amount
            )
        ]
    )
    db.session.add(my_fund_src)
    db.session.commit()
    ...
```

Comment: That definitely makes sense! When I tried adding a new allocation though, I got this error: TypeError: 'allocation' is an invalid keyword argument for FundingSource

Comment: Sorry about that, in this case you need to reference the relationship name and provide a list. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: @Ez-Pz did my edit solve your problem? If so, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, when I try it again, it's giving me the error: "NOT NULL constraint failed: funding_source.department" because department is an attribute in the FundingSource table but not in the AllocationSummary table. It can't be null though, but I also don't need it for insert. So how am I suppose to include it in "my_fund_src" without it getting inserted? Thanks for all the help

Comment: That's a completely different situation. If you don't need it for insert, then by definition it should be nullable.

Comment: Department can't be nullable for FundingSource purposes, cause for that table, you need that attribute, but for the AllocationSummary table, you don't need it. So there's no way to call the 4 needed attributes from FundingSource for inserting into AllocationSummary without calling the Department parameter since it's non-nullable?

Comment: No. The only reason you have access to those 4 attributes is because of the relationship. A relationship indicates a JOIN on another table in order for sqlalchemy to make those properties available via `my_fund_src.allocations[0].*` commands. So, when adding an allocation it _must be a valid record_. Net net, either you'll need to make those fields nullable or rethink you db schema.